How can I connect a water line to refrigerator more than 10 feet away?
A plumber told me I can’t have a 10 ft water line from my sink to refrigerator ice maker. It’s not up to California code but they can hook two 8ft lines together, or put a box in and look for nearest water line. The line would run behind the cupboards to the refrigerator. Is there a better way to do this?

Ask a different plumber.

if it is a 1/4 inch copper line you can

The plumber may be referring to Does the California plumbing code require a water line shutoff behind a refrigerator?, which the question fails to explain. I'm voting to close as a duplicate since that question seems to cover both shutoff location and supply type (at least in comments--answers could be improved).
